# How to detect edge lines in OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, contour

After segmentation the input image looks like this:
[image: segmented image]

Now how do I detect the edge lines shown below:
[image: edges to detect]

I have tried HoughLines but that seemed to return only the bottom line.

My goal is to crop out the marked area in following image:
[image: crop area]

Answer (score 0):

If you always have such good edges (edges with no holes) for your big rectangle, and all components inside this rectangle are always significantly smaller, you can use `connectedComponentsWithStats()`, which will yield edges with their length, and then select the longest edge(s). In Python :

```
nb_edges, output, size, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=8)
#then select the edge with the biggest size
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on how can I find the edges? trying `connectedComponentsWithStats` in java I have found a labeled image which has only the inner components that have a closed path, and a stats matrix that contains rectangles for those components. where should I look for the lines?